# 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.' error in sql c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to connect tot he database and extract the contents, but whenever I try, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

I'm not sure why no data is being read from the table, it seems to work perfectly fine when I connect to the other table I have in the database.

This is the code I use:

```
static void testcon()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Programe.connectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Auth WHERE Username = @username", con);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", "test");

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);

    con.Close();
}
```

The exception was thrown on this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
```

This is the server explorer:

[image]

I have tried trying different key words in the SQL commands, different keywords in the method but I keep getting the same error.

I have tried

```
if (reader.read())
{
    //code here
}
```

but that wouldn't solve my issue as the data not being present would still occur

Comment: The `if` test at the bottom should have done the job;  can we see the version with that? Also, have you considered tools like Dapper? Makes it much easier to get raw data access correct

Comment: @MarcGravell what's dapper?

Comment: popular helper API for simple SQL operations, readily available on nuget; https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper - originally written for Stack Overflow's usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

You can print column name as per your need.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
      while (reader.Read()) //The loop will run for all the rows in the result.
      {
          //loop on all the columns
          for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while(reader.read())
{
// code here
}
```

Comment: See code at the end of the question - looks like OP is vaguely aware of this already

Comment: if read gives another result as while read